# pushviewcontroller causing memory leak in ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am really surprised that instruments shows memory leak at pushviewcontroller in my code while I am having ARC enabled in my code. Following is my code:

```
AddCallDetailsViewController *lAddCallDetailsViewController=[[AddCallDetailsViewController alloc]init];
lAddCallDetailsViewController.isAllDay = isAllDay;
lAddCallDetailsViewController.delegate = self;
lAddCallDetailsViewController.currentDayinCalender = curdate;
lAddCallDetailsViewController.isFromEditCall = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:lAddCallDetailsViewController animated:YES];
```

And following is the backtrace of instruments that shows 100% leak at that point.

Any help in removing this issue will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: is this happening each and every time when you try to push the viewcontroller

Comment: Moreover, I got many questions on this forum of same kind but most of them are Pre-ARC and the ones ARC enabled are not having any apposite answer that solves the problem completely.

Comment: Whenever i try to run instruments, Its shows this problem...

Comment: What object is being leaked (Instruments can tell you this)? Is it possible that your delegate property is `strong` and not `weak`? If so, then that would cause a retain loop between your `EditCallViewController` and `AddCallDetailsViewController`.

Comment: @Malaxeur : My delegate property is (nonatomic, retain) in AddCallDetailsViewControlle. Can it really cause a memory leak? If yes, what should I amend to resolve this problem??

Comment: @Ad-J looking at your code more closely, no. When the lAddCallDetailsViewController is popped, it should be deallocated and the reference back to self should be cleared out. However, your delegate properties should always have a `weak` reference back to the delegate. This will prevent retain cycles between two objects... i.e A holds on to B, B holds on to A.

Comment: @Malaxeur: According to your suggestion I tried to change the property type to unsafe_unretained and also to weak but has not effect on leak problem. Though when I just changed the scope of Object to class, leak disappeared. My problem is solved now but still I am looking for suitable explanation for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Try to increase the scope of "lAddCallDetailsViewController" To class level..
In .h file or private scope in .m file.

```
AddCallDetailsViewController *lAddCallDetailsViewController;
```

In .m file

```
lAddCallDetailsViewController=[[AddCallDetailsViewController alloc]init];
lAddCallDetailsViewController.isAllDay = isAllDay;
lAddCallDetailsViewController.delegate = self;
lAddCallDetailsViewController.currentDayinCalender = curdate;
lAddCallDetailsViewController.isFromEditCall = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:lAddCallDetailsViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason that changing scope will resolve this problem? I am having so many objects and increasing scope at class level might create some problem in my code....

Comment: While changing the scope as class level, the allocation will be done only if there is no such instance in the memory.

Comment: Though changing the scope of the object to class level has solved my problem, It would really be great help if u can explain me the reason behind all this as well???